# centering table caption in a class created by my university

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, templates, alignment, documentclass

I am using a document class written by my university. I tried to put the caption of my table in the center. However, I could not manage to do that.

Please find a working example and the files in this [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1mG4B86EP18rgo9ZqtL7GQdoO18CM8xqy?usp=sharing). I have put a test table with a caption. Just run it, you can see that the caption is left aligned. Please see the figure below:
[image]

Could anyone help me?

Note that I tried `\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}`, but it did not help.
I appreciate it in advance.

Comment: Note that in the case of a table, the caption is often put before of the table (in contrast to Figure captions).

Comment: thanks @Karlo, I will put the caption on the top of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to modify the file `UUThesisTemplate.cls` directly.

Add `\center` below `\def\@makecaption@table#1#2{%` as shown here:

```
\def\@makecaption@table#1#2{%
    \center
    \addvspace{\belowcaptionskip}%
    %\sbox\@tempboxa{{\bf #1.} #2}%
    \small{\bf #1.} {\it #2}\par%
    \addvspace{\abovecaptionskip}%
}
```

When compiling the file `Thesis.tex`, this gives

[image]